# Can't resize gedit window (Cinnamon with Radiance theme)

Tags: themes, gedit, cinnamon, radiance

I'm using the [Radiance](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/14.04+16.04.20160804-0ubuntu1) theme (I think it's installed by default on Ubuntu) but since the update to Ubuntu 16.04 I can't resize gedit's window with the mouse. It works if I select a different theme in System Settings -> Themes in Cinnamon.

Answer (score 1):

There are other methods, how to resize window, when the default method is broken.

---

### 1.

Right click on top panel and choose "Resize". Then resize window how you want.

[image]

---

### 2.

The second better method is keyboard shortcut *Alt + Middle mouse button* (wheel).

Hold down the *Alt* key and press and hold the *middle mouse button*.

---

I think that the second method is more comfortable then resizing through the window edges.

Comment: Thanks but this is not a real fix, it works with the other default themes so I think the fix lies within editing the theme itself. I tried to port over some changes from the working themes, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Add these two lines to the bottom of the /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css file:

@import url("apps/xfce.css");
@import url("apps/gtk3-window-deco.css");

Download and copy these two files from the "Ambiance-Crunchy" theme.

Answer (score 0):

## Ubuntu 16.04

Finally, I found it. I was suspicious about its edges, other GTK3 applications have a thin solid border (1px) with correct external shadow decoration.

- Add

  ```
  GeditWindow {
      margin: 5px;
  }
  ```

  to the top of

  ```
  /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/apps/gedit.css
  /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/gedit.css
  ```

I expect this fix to work with other GTK3 app (with HeaderBar) facing same issue.

Comment: I have just tried this -- no change at all, even after a reboot. Then I have renamed gedit.css to gedit.css_ in both folders and the corresponding gtk-3.20 folders. Still no difference.... How do I know which of those files is actually used? Gnome terminal works as expected, but I think other gnome apps have the same issue as gedit. I have updated my ubuntu installation once or twice (I am at 16.10 now), could that be related? Did you have the same problem?

Comment: @StefanHaustein, I have tried that in 16.04, I will check it  in 16.10 and let you know.

Comment: @StefanHaustein, I confirm the issue with 16.10, the previous fix didn't work. May be some other file override it, i will check it.